Import worker from webpack library in Angular project
I'm trying to load a webpack library (that I own) using web workers in an Angular app.
To build the lib I run npm run build && npm pack. The dist folder correctly contains 2 files:

lib.js: the library code
408.lib.js: the worker code

I import the lib in the app using npm i ../lib/lib-1.0.0.tgz. Lib & worker files are correctly imported in the app's node_modules/lib folder.
However when trying to use the lib's worker from the Angular app, I get a 404 error, as Angular does not exposes the lib's worker.
How can I do that?
Here's the code:
lib/webpack.config.js:
const Path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'lib.js',
        globalObject: 'this',
        library: {
            name: 'webpackNumbers',
            type: 'umd'
        },
    }
};

lib/package.json:
{
  "name": "lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/lib.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

lib/src/index.js:
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));

export function testWorker() {

    worker.postMessage({
        question: 'The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything.',
    });
    worker.onmessage = ({ data: { answer } }) => {
        console.log(answer);
    };
}

lib/src/worker.js:
self.onmessage = ({ data: { question } }) => {
    self.postMessage({
        answer: 42,
    });
};

app/src/app/app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import * as lib from 'lib';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() {
    lib.testWorker();
  }
}


I found a solution: just add the following to the app's angular.json (in projects > app > architect > build > assets):
{
  "glob": "*",
  "input": "node_modules/lib/dist/",
  "output": "/"
}

Would be better to find a way without having to update the app's config but it will do for now.
